# Restriction of a stable bundle on a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb P^N$ be a smooth projective surface. Let $H$ be an ample divisor on $X$. Let $M_{X,H}(r;c_1,c_2)$ be the moduli space of rank r, slope stable (w.r.to $H$) vector bundles with fixed Chern classes $c_1,c_2$. Let $C$ be a smooth curve lying on $X$ such that for every $E \in M_{X,H}(r;c_1,c_2)$, $E|_{C}$ is semistable on $C$. Then we have a natural map from $M_{X,H}(r;c_1,c_2)$ to $M_C(r, d)$ (moduli of semistable bundles of rank $r$ and degree $d$ on the curve $C$) given by $E \mapsto E|_C$. My questions are :

$(i)$ Is this map a morphism between these two moduli schemes?

$(ii)$ If so, then is it an injective morphism? (I guess in rank $1$ case it is injective, please correct me if this is wrong)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for (1), because the restriction gives a morphism of moduli functors, hence also of their coarse moduli spaces.

No for (2), even in the rank 1 case; consider for instance $X = Y \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $C = \{y_0\} \times \mathbb{P}^1$, where $Y$ is a smooth curve of positive genus and $y_0 \in Y$ is a point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Can we say that $(2)$ is true if we carefully choose curves on the surface say $\mathbb P^2$ or hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^3$? ( Or is it the case that it is almost never true?)

Comment: (2) is true if you take $C$ in $|nH|$ with $n \gg 0$, where $H$ is an ample class on $X$.

Comment: On $\mathbb P^2$, if we take $H$ to be the divisor corresponding to $\mathcal O(1)$, then can we give an effective bound on $n$?

Comment: Probably yes, but I am not an expert in this. Maybe a good idea is to look through the papers of Soheyla Feyzbakhsh.